# Randomly group of array content in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have this kind of array

```
 Array(
        [0]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 0'
                 [link]        => 'Link 0'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 0'
                 [content]     => 'Content 0'
             )
        [1]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 1'
                 [link]        => 'Link 1'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 1'
                 [content]     => 'Content 1'
             )
        [2]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 2'
                 [link]        => 'Link 2'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 2'
                 [content]     => 'Content 2'
             )
    )
```

How can I shuffle between [content],[excerpt] and [title],[link]
So basically it's gonna look something similar like this

```
 Array(
        [0]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 0'
                 [link]        => 'Link 0'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 1'
                 [content]     => 'Content 1'
             )
        [1]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 1'
                 [link]        => 'Link 1'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 2'
                 [content]     => 'Content 2'
             )
        [2]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 2'
                 [link]        => 'Link 2'
                 [excerpt]     => 'Excerpt 0'
                 [content]     => 'Content 0'
             )
    )
```

If shuffle entire array content I can do that, but this case I still confuse, anyone can help me?

Thank you

Patty

Comment: You want that `excerpt` and `contents` change, but not `title` and `link`?

Comment: @Syscall yes thats correct, but in 1 condition, excerpt and contents must be keep together just like title and link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to get the values, then, shuffle the keys, and finally, update the contents using the same "shuffled" key:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'title'   => 'Title 0',
        'link'    => 'Link 0',
        'excerpt' => 'Excerpt 0',
        'content' => 'Content 0'
    ),
    array(
        'title'   => 'Title 1',
        'link'    => 'Link 1',
        'excerpt' => 'Excerpt 1',
        'content' => 'Content 1'
    ),
    array(
        'title'   => 'Title 2',
        'link'    => 'Link 2',
        'excerpt' => 'Excerpt 2',
        'content' => 'Content 2'
    )
);

// get data
$excerpts = array_column($array, 'excerpt');
$contents = array_column($array, 'content');
// get keys and shuffle them
$keys = array_keys($array);
shuffle($keys);
// iterate over array (and pass $values as reference)
foreach ($array as $key => &$values) {
    // get the new shuffled key
    $rand_key = $keys[$key];
    // update content
    $values['excerpt'] = $excerpts[$rand_key];
    $values['content'] = $contents[$rand_key];
}
print_r($array);
```

Could outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 0
            [link] => Link 0
            [excerpt] => Excerpt 0
            [content] => Content 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
            [link] => Link 1
            [excerpt] => Excerpt 2
            [content] => Content 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [link] => Link 2
            [excerpt] => Excerpt 1
            [content] => Content 1
        )

)
```